LilyPond: can sustain pedal automatically avoid fingering?
Here is the original engraving I am trying to reproduce

Here is my LilyPond code
\version "2.24.3"
\language "italiano"

cu = { \change Staff = "right" }
cd = { \change Staff = "left" }
hideNoteHead = \once {
    \omit Stem
    \omit Dots
    \omit Flag
    \hideNotes
    \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t
}

global = {
    \key reb \major
    \time 9/8
}

right = \new Staff = "right" {
    \global
    \relative do'' {
        r8 r8 s8 s4. <reb fa>
    }
}

left = \new Staff = "left" {
    \global
    \relative do' {
        r8
        <<
            \new Voice {
                \voiceOne
                <fa_4 lab_2> \sustainOn
                \oneVoice
                \cu <fa' lab>~ 4. \hideNoteHead fa4 s8 |
            }
            {
                \once \hideNotes <fa, lab>4~ 2. |
            }
        >>
    }
    <solb' la'>2. \sustainOff \sustainOn ~4.
}

\new PianoStaff {
    <<
        \right
        \left
    >>
}

And this is the result

The pedal sign overlaps with fingering. I guess I can try shifting the pedal sign, but can LilyPond make the pedal avoid fingering automatically?

The solution is to place fingering under hidden notes. I guess it has something to do with voices. Maybe a bug?
\version "2.24.3"
\language "italiano"

\language "italiano"

cu = { \change Staff = "right" }
cd = { \change Staff = "left" }
hideNoteHead = \once {
    \omit Stem
    \omit Dots
    \omit Flag
    \hideNotes
    \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t
}

global = {
    \key reb \major
    \time 9/8
}

right = \new Staff = "right" {
    \global
    \relative do'' {
        r8 r8 s8 s4. <reb fa>
    }
}

left = \new Staff = "left" {
    \global
    \relative do' {
        r8
        <<
            \new Voice {
                \voiceOne
                <fa lab> \sustainOn
                \oneVoice
                \cu <fa' lab>~ 4. \hideNoteHead fa4 s8 |
            }
            {
                \once \hideNotes <fa,_4 lab_2>4~ 2. |
            }
        >>
    }
    <solb' la'>2. \sustainOff \sustainOn ~4.
}

\new PianoStaff {
    <<
        \right
        \left
    >>
}



Yes, that is reasonable. The issue here is not the voices, but the staff change. I do not understand this fully yet, but I assume that due to the staff change somehow the fingerings are somehow assumed to belong to the other staff, and thus it is not considered for resolving collisions.

Hmm... Even in the first example, the fingering precedes the staff change. Do you think it still somehow got associated with another staff?
